# How to calculate the Witten-Reshetikhin-Turaev invariants from a triangulation?

Tags: topological-quantum-field-theory, extended-tqft, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

I'm interested in the Witten-Reshetikhin-Turaev invariants for 3-manifolds, and in particular, how to calculate them from a *triangulation* of the 3-manifold (recall that as they were first introduced, their calculation is based on a surgery diagram for the manifold).  Is there any some sort of "state sum" model giving the WRT invariant for a $3$-manifold, which is based on the triangulation of the $3$-manifold?

I am well aware of the Turaev-Viro construction, and it is exactly the type of definition I'm hoping for, but of course the TV invariant is $\left|\cdot\right|^2$ of the WRT invariant, not the WRT invariant itself.

The simpler the construction, the better.  Certainly one can go algorithmically from a triangulation to a surgery diagram, but I want something which is conceptually based on the triangulation.

I guess any answer I get will also include the case for a pair $(Y^3,L)$, and even perhaps allow for $M^3$ to have nonempty boundary (i.e. the full tqft).  However, I will be satisfied  even if I just get a construction for a closed $3$-manifold $M$.

Comment: This is a well-known open problem. (minor point: you can go algorithmically from surgery presentations to triangulations, but not the other way so easily).

Comment: If you let the 3-manifold bound a 4-manifold and extend the triangulation, it's not an open problem.  A version of the Crane-Yetter state sum calculates the WRT invariant in that case.  See my answer below.

Comment: I am wondering why noone mentioned that if $\mathcal C$ is the Drinf'ld center $Z(\mathcal F)$ of a fusion category $\mathcal F$ then the TV construction applied to $\mathcal F$ does the job. For sure this does just works for certain MTCs (the trivial Witt class?!?).

Answer (score 14):

This can be done if you extend the triangulation of your 3-manifold $M$ to a triangulation of a 4-manifold $W$ whose boundary is $M$.  You can find the basic idea in Chapter 9 of [these draft notes](http://canyon23.net/math/tc.pdf) on my web page, and there are very explicit details for the associated Hilbert space in [this arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2632) (with Z. Wang).  (In the latter paper we use cubes instead of simplices to make computer implementation easier.)  There's also a summary in the [notes from a talk](http://canyon23.net/math/talks/ucb%20frg%20200901.pdf).

The main idea is that the Witten-Reshetikhin-Turaev TQFT can be reinterpreted as a 3+1-dimensional TQFT, and the 3+1-dimensional version is "fully extended" (goes all the way down to points).  Once you have a fully extended TQFT, standard techniques allow you to construct a state sum model.  In this case, the state sum you get is a modified version of the Crane-Yetter state sum.  (You would get a Turaev-Viro state sum for a fully extended 2+1 dimensional TQFT.)

---

EDIT:

If you don't want to wade through the above sources, here's the explicit formula.

Let $C$ be a modular ribbon category.
Let $D= \sqrt{\sum_i d_i^2}$, the square root of the sum of the squares of the quantum dimensions.
Choose a handle decomposition of $W^4$.
Keep in mind is the case where the $i$-handles are thickenings of the $i$-cells
of some cell decomposition of $W$, such as the dual cell decomposition to a triangulation.
Let ${\cal H}_i$ be the set of $i$-handles.
Let ${\cal L}_2$ be the set of labelings of the 2-handles by simple objects of $C$.
For fixed $\alpha\in{\cal L}_2$, let ${\cal L}_1(\alpha)$ denote the set of labelings of the 1-handles by orthogonal
basis elements of the associated vertex spaces.
(To each 1-handle is associated a $C$-picture on the linking 2-sphere,
that is, a collection $c$ of
ribbon endpoints on the 2-sphere labeled by simple objects
$a_1\otimes \cdots\otimes a_m$ according to $\alpha$.
The "vertex space" is $\hom_C(1, a_1\otimes\cdots\otimes a_m)$ or,
more canonically, the vector space associated to $(B^3; c)$, where we think
of $B^3$ as the normal fiber to the core of the 1-handle.)
Then
$$Z(W^4) = \sum_{\alpha\in{\cal L}_2} \sum_{\beta\in{\cal L}_1(\alpha)}
 \prod_{h_4\in {\cal H}_4} D
 \prod_{h_3\in {\cal H}_3} D^{-1}
 \prod_{h_2\in {\cal H}_2} D^{-1} \,\text{Loop}(h_2, \alpha)\quad\quad\quad\quad$$
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\prod_{h_1\in {\cal H}_1} D \,\text{Th}(h_1, \beta)^{-1}
 \prod_{h_0\in {\cal H}_0} D^{-1} \, \text{Link}(h_0, \alpha, \beta) , $$

where

- $\text{Loop}(h_2, \alpha)$ is the loop value (quantum dimension) of the simple object $\alpha(h_2)$;
- $\text{Th}(h_1, \beta)$ is the evaluation of generalized theta graph with the two vertices
  labeled by $\beta(h_1)$ and $\overline{\beta(h_1)}$ (in the case of a generic cell decomposition where each 1-cell is incident to three 2-cells, this is just an ordinary theta graph); and
- $\text{Link}(h_0, \alpha, \beta)$ is the evaluation of the graph in  $S^3$ corresponding to the link
  of the 0-handle $h_0$, labeled according to $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

If $W$ has a boundary $M$ then we can place a labeled link $L$ in the boundary, and the labels of the link play a role similar to the labels of the 2-handles above.  In this case the state sum computes $WRT(M, L)$.

For a generic cell decomposition of $W$ (i.e. dual to a triangulation), the $\text{Link}(h_0, \alpha, \beta)$ factor is an evaluation of a labeled ribbon graph which looks like the 1-skeleton of a 4-simplex.  If we resolve the five 4-valent vertices oin this graph into pairs of 3-valent vertices, then this becomes the "15-j symbol" used by Crane and Yetter.  (Keep in mind that Crane and Yetter use a different normalization which obscures the relation to the WRT invariant.)

On the other hand, if we choose a handle decomposition of $W$ with a single 0-handle and several 2-handles (no 1- 3- or 4-handles), then it is easy to see that the above state sum reduces to the Reshetikhin-Turaev surgery formula.  The factor $\text{Link}(h_0, \alpha, \beta)$ is the generalized Jones polynomial (evaluated at a root of unity) in this case.

A similar variant yields the Turaev "shadow" state sum.

Comment: Is finding a triangulated 4-manifold with your 3-manifold as boundary substantially easier than just presenting it as surgery on a link, which is presumably what the author is what the author is trying to avoid? (Going from the former to the latter is just picking a Morse function...)

Comment: @Ben: No, not substantially easier so far as I know.  But I didn't think that ease of calculation was the motivation for the question.  There could be other reasons to prefer thinking in terms of triangulations.  Locality, for example.

Comment: What are the "standard techniques" that can magically turn an ETQFT into a state sum model? Can you point out any resources or is it more of a folk theorem?

Comment: @Turion: See the draft notes I link to in the answer above, especially the last paragraph of Chapter 6 (for the general case) and Chapters 8 and 9 (more specific examples).

Comment: @Kevin: If $W^4$ is a closed 4-manifold, what is this topological invariant $Z(W^4)$. I heard that it is related to the signature of $W^4$ but do not know the exact form.

Comment: For $W^4$ closed, $Z(W^4) = C^{\sigma(W)}$, where $C$ is the exponentiated central charge (a root of unity) and $\sigma(W)$ is the signature of $W$.  I'm assuming that the input is a modular category (rather than merely a premodular category) and that the Euler characteristic normalization has been chosen correctly.  Crane and Yetter used a different normalization, which lead to an additional factor of $a^{\chi(W)}$.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks. Is $C=exp(i c \pi/4)$ where $c$ is the usual chiral central charge (assuming the input to be a modular category)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  $C$ depends only on $c$ modulo 8.

Comment: @KevinWalker: How do you choose the framing of the ribbon graph that evaluates to $\mathop{Link}(h_0,\alpha,\beta)$? Seems like for generic triangulations/cell complexes additional decorations are necessary to determine the framing. E.g.we need an ordering of the vertices of the link of each edge, in order to determine in which order the different ribbons enter the corresponding coupon...

Comment: @AndiBauer - You can choose the framings and orderings any way you like for computing $Link(h_0, \alpha, \beta)$, so long as you make the same/corresponding choices when computing $Th(h_1, \beta)$ (which perhaps should have been called $Th(h_1,\alpha,  \beta)$).  This is analogous to the following fact.  Suppose we want to compose some linear maps.  By choosing bases in the intermediate vector spaces, we can convert this to a computation of multiplying matrices.  The matrices depend on the choice of basis, but so long as...

Comment: ... you use the same basis choice for adjacent matrices, the final answer will not vary (even though the individual matrices DO vary when you use a different basis).

Comment: ah yeah, sure, changing the order for two glued coupons simultaneously doesn't change anything. I was thinking more about that, in order to even specify the framing for the link of a vertex, one needs to fix those orders.

Comment: Is the following interpretation of your state-sum above correct? Using the gluing axiom of the Reshetikhin-Turaev TQFT for the input (pre)modular fusion category, we get that the partition function for a fixed label set $\alpha$ is equal to the Reshetikin-Turaev invariant for the following ribbon-link 3-manifold: The manifold itself is the boundary of the union of $0$-handles and $1$-handles (corresponding to vertices and edges). Along each loop winding around the $0$- and $1$-handles adjacent to each face there is a ribbon with the corresponding label?

Comment: If so, then what it the winding number of this ribbon loop around a face? Is it always untwisted? Or is there one single twist? The occurence of $C=\sum_i \theta_i d_i^2/D$ in the partition function (for modular input) suggests that there should be some remaining twists...

Comment: (I guess, "being untwisted" doesn't necessarily always make sense for loops that are not contractable. The loops around the $0$- and $1$-handles around a face are contractable after we perform the surgery move corresponding to the according $2$-handle, so this should still be a well defined question?)

Comment: If you modify the above sum by using only the "Th" and "Link" factors (associated to 0- and 1-handles), then it computes the WRT invariant you describe.  2-handles are always attached along *framed* links, so the 2-handle attachment data determines the framings you were asking about.

Comment: Thanks! Another small question: Do I assume correctly that $\mathop{Th}(h_1,\alpha,\beta)$ is the ribbon graph in the $3$-sphere with two coupons connected by $n$ ribbons (where $n$ is the number of faces adjacent to the edge $h_1$), in an untwisted manner? Doesn't this always evaluate to the identity matrix on the $\beta$ labels, such that this term could be left out? Or is precisely the point in $\mathop{Th}$ that the ribbons between the two coupons can be twisted and change their order, which would result in an isometry identifying the two $\beta$-labelled fusion spaces of the coupons?

Comment: Yes, untwisted.  The label $\beta$ uses an orthogonal basis of the "vertex space" (this is not standard terminology), so if we think of this as a matrix indexed by labels associated to the two endpoints of the 1-handle, then it will be a diagonal matrix (because of orthogonality).  If we like, we can use an orthonormal basis (rather than merely orthogonal), in which case $Th(...) = 1$ always.  But this basis choice will also affect the values of $Link(...)$.  Standard basis choices, in both the physics and math literature, are orthogonal but typically not orthonormal.

Comment: Do you know a reference where it's explained how your state-sum (for modular input) evaluates to $C^{\sigma(W)}$ on a triangulation of a $4$-manifold $W$?

Comment: And: Is it true that (again for modular input) your state-sum can be transformed into an ordinary product of numbers on the cellulation? (Namely, starting from the sum over the ribbon-link manifolds from my comment above, then applying the surgery identity $\sum_\alpha \mathop{Loop}(\alpha)/D [\text{sol. torus w. }\alpha\text{-flux}]=[\text{dual sol. torus}]$ around each $2$-cell, and further identities on the $1$- and $0$-cells?)

Comment: Check out chapter 9 of http://canyon23.net/math/tc.pdf .

Comment: The relationship with the signature of a closed 4-manifold goes back to Crane-Yetter-Kauffman.  Their version differs from mine by an Euler characteristic normalization, but that's a pretty minor difference.

Comment: The state sum in my original answer is already a sum of ordinary products of numbers determined by labelings of the cellulation.  If you prefer to work with triangulations, you should take the cellulation above to be dual to the triangulation you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks! No, I really mean just a product of numbers on the cellulation, without any summing. There are local combinatorial formulas for the signature of a $4$-manifold, so it should be possible to write $C^{\sigma(W)}$ as a product of complex numbers associated to different components of the cellulation. Just in the same way in which it is possible to write $D^{\chi(W)}$ as a product of factors $D$ or $D^{-1}$ associated to the different $n$-cells (with $\chi$ the Euler characteristic).

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking for is essentially equivalent to making Witten-Reshetikhin-Turaev theory into an [extended topological quantum field theory](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/cobordism.pdf) (= "local field theory").

Modulo a whole bunch of stuff, this is what we have achieved in my [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5307) with A. Bartels and C. Douglas. Of course, there is still *A LOT* to do before those results can be turned into an effective procedure for computing 3-manifold invariants.
Also (and quite importantly), we don't know yet that the local field theories constructed in that paper are really the same as Witten-Reshetikhin-Turaev...

Comment: Does an extended TQFT really give a way of computing invariants from triangulations?  Don't you need an open-closed extended TQFT?  Just think about 2 dimensions.

Comment: Isn't "open-closed" the same thing as "extended"?... (please tell me what you have in mind, because I'm not quite following your comment) The real problem is that you need to have framings around (or p_1-structures). If we were just talking about oriented TQFT's then triangulations should be just fine as input data.

Comment: Like André, I thought that an open-closed 2d TQFT was the same thing as a fully extended 2d TQFT.  And I'm not sure what "open-closed" would mean in higher dimensions.  I'm curious to hear what Noah had in mind.

Comment: "Open-closed" means you allow a different kind of boundary which you're not allowed to glue along.  This is definitely a different concept than extending.  It's more closely related to allowing boundaries between two different TFTs, but where one of the TFTs is trivial.  I'm still a little confused though about the relationship of each of these notions (extended and open-closed) to triangulations, so I'm going to think some more about that before saying anything.

Comment: Thanks Noah.  Some part of my brain knew that already, but apparently that part was not in communication with the parts which were doing the typing yesterday.  So an extended 2d TQFT, plus some representations of the 1-category associated to a point (to label non-gluing boundaries), gives rise to an open-closed 2d TQFT.  I suppose all open-closed TQFTs might arise this way, depending on the details of one's definition of an open-closed TQFT.

Comment: On the one hand, given an extended TFT you can certainly compute its values using a triangulation. However, this process is a bit more complicated than you might expect (see pps. 4-5 of http://www.math.utexas.edu/users/odavidovich/Talks/BerkleyNov2010 for some discussion of these issues). On the other hand, I don't think you get the state sum model directly from an extended TFT. Instead to get the state sum model directly you really want an open-closed theory. In 2d you remove a little window around every vertex of your triangulation, compute that and then normalize.

Comment: I think state sums can be derived more simply and directly than is outlined in the talk you link to.  (In the 2d case, I'm assuming Z(pt) is a semisimple 1-cat with finitely many simple objects.  I'm not sure how much G-equivariance complicates things, but I suspect not much.)  You just apply gluing formulas in a straightforward way to the handle decomposition associated to the cell decomposition, choosing orthogonal bases and idempotents at every step.

Comment: This talk tries to clarify (amongst other things) which compositions (horizontal or vertical) have to be used for which parts of the 0-, 1- and 2-handles. Is there really a straightforward generalisation of doing this in the n-dimensional case, where you have n different compositions?

Answer (score 3):

Hi, we (Ricardo Machado and Sostenes Lins) put in arxiv, 3 articles which shows how to get a framed link presentation from a triangulation. We show an O(n^2) algorithm which I implemented and it is really working. So with the framed link we can calculate the WRT-invariants

The link to the articles:
http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+AND+lins+AND+sostenes+AND+ricardo+Machado/0/1/0/all/0/1